# Custom directive eats comma in Mozilla

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive, it's validate the input number and allow you to input a number in such format: `0000.00000`
Everything works fine but only in Chrome. When I open Mozilla it eats my comma. I've tried to use `ng-trim`, but it doesn't work. Does anybody had such a problem?

My Directive with validation rule:

```js
 .directive('float', function() {
   var isValid = function(str) {
     // return true;
     var regex = /^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:(\.|,)\d{1,5})?$/;
     return regex.test(str);
   };

   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

       ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
         var validate = isValid(viewValue);
         ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('float', validate);
         return validate ? parseFloat(viewValue.replace(',', '.')) : null;
       });

       elm.bind('keyup change', function() {
         if (angular.isFunction(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.replace)) {
           ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.replace(/[^\d{0,16}(.|,)]/g, ""));
           ngModelCtrl.$render();
           scope.$apply();
         }
       });
     }
   };
 });
```

This is my input field:

```html
<label class="control-label">Amount min</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input 
         type="number" 
         step="any" 
         min="0" 
         ng-model="form.amount_min" 
         float 
         name="amount_min" 
         minmax='{"name": "amount_max", "order": "minimum"}' 
         validerror="{name: 'amount_min'}"
         ng-trim="false">
</div>
```

Comment: `"0000,00000".replace(/[^\d{0,16}(.|,)]/g, "")` works for me in Firefox. I notice your regex isnt quite right tho - you have surrounded the whole thing with `[]` which is a character set match. So other characters in there such as `{` will remain.